# How to Return 'Invalid Email' if User Doesn't Enter Correct Format

Tags: javascript, prompt

I am trying to prompt the user to enter their email. If the email is an invalid email, then it should prompt "Please enter a valid email". Below is the code I have. However, no matter ***what*** I enter, it keeps looping through the while loop. I've read some other articles from here that have kind of the same concept, and while it may answer the question to people who have been doing this for several years, the "explanations" don't answer how to fix my issue, which is why I am asking.

```
//Function to validate email //

function validEmail(email) {
    const emailRegex = /[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}/;
    const valid = email.match(emailRegex);
    return valid;
};

const emailAddress = prompt('Please enter your email');
while (!validEmail(emailAddress)) {
    prompt('Please enter a valid email');
    // console.log('Please enter a valid email');
}
```

Comment: the problem is .. `emailAddress` is set once ... all the other values entered in the `prompt` inside the while loop won't change `emailAddress`

Comment: Because `emailAddress` is always the result of the first `prompt`. Use `let` and reassign the variable to the result of the new `prompt`.

Comment: If you use that Regex you're in for a world of hurt. Already it'll fail on `somebody@example.museum` or `somebody@example.accountant` (and many other long TLDs). It will also fail `somebody@office.example.com`. Then there's non-english characters and emoji domains. Yes `@.fm` is a valid email address.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Uh-oh! What do you suggest I put instead?

Comment: @HereticMonkey so emailAddress = ?

Comment: @tyler308956 Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/14853083), and the expression in the first answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: @PeterJames Not at all ): I already read through that one and I couldn't find anything I understood. Doesn't really relate to my scenario. Seems more advanced

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular The explanation doesn't make sense to me. Way too abstract ): That's why I asked the question (: (learning disability)

Comment: As a meta comment, the correct answer is to not validate email addresses, because for practical intents and purposes, almost any string that has `@` in it can be a valid email address.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, your regex will fail for many email addresses that are actually valid.  However, to get around the repeated prompting issue, try this:

```
let emailAddress = prompt('Please enter your email');
while (!validEmail(emailAddress)) {
    emailAddress = prompt('Please enter a valid email');
}
```

Your original code always checks the user's first input only.  `emailAddress` should be a variable rather than a constant in order to allow repeatedly assigning values to it.  Then assign the result of every prompt to `emailAddress` in order to get the user's *latest* input.